# How to load a specific number of records per page and add an more button

Tags: ajax, typo3, typo3-9.x

On my page I would like to output all records of a specific folder 
but the number should initially be limited to a certain quantity (to reduce the loading times). With a "Load more" button further records should be loaded.

Does anyone have a hint on how I can achieve this?

I have already found several approaches on the web in connection with AJAX, but since I'm not familiar with this yet, more questions than answers have emerged ...

For info: I use an own Template Extension / Distribution under Typo3 9.5.8

Thank you in advance for any help!!

Answer (score 0):

The state of the art solution is the AJAX solution, where you load only the required records from the server and modify the page on the fly.

Another option would be an URL parameter which is evaluated by your extension.
With the parameter the full list is shown,
without only the first N and a button with the link to the same URL including the parameter for the full list.
Make sure the paramter is handled correctly and generates another cached version of the page. (keywords: cHash)
As you now have two pages with partially identical content: don't forget to tell the searchengines that the short variant should not be indexed.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Paginate Widget like documented here: https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/9.5/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Widget/Paginate.html

By overriding the paginate template file and only rendering the pagination.nextPage link, you could load the nextpage via AJAX.